# PHP Convert dynamic variable array to tree array

Tags: php, arrays, tree

I have an array like:

```
array(
    0 => array("a", "b", "c", ... n),
    1 => array("a", "b", "d", ... n),
    2 => array("e", "b", "c", ... n),
    .
    n
    );
```

With n lenght right and down.
I want an tree array like:

```
a {
    b {
        c {null}
        d {null}
       }
  }
e {
   b {
      c {null}
     }
  }
```

Extactly, something like:
[How to convert array to tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663096/how-to-convert-array-to-tree)
but in PHP code and for 'n' lenght array

My code, translated from javascript:

```
$tree = array();

function addToTree($tree, $array) {
    $length = count($array);
    for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
        $tree = $tree[$array[$i]] = (($i == $length - 1) ? null : $tree[$array[$i]] || array());
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your tree array needs to look like. What you show does not look right.

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Maybe this question helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647745/create-an-associative-array-from-a-string/32648184#32648184

Comment: As I see from the referred question the question is in same manner as that so is there A change in questions asking technique ? @JohnConde

Comment: @IshanMahajan Seven years ago the standards at this site were much more lax. It has been clarified that questions like these are too broad and should be closed as such.

Comment: Sorry all, i have been traying doing this for three days, i didnt paste my code because I never got run it right, my code was (is) wrong.
I have been searching a lot before asking for help.
Anyway, thanks, and sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is same as Christians answer just you have to edit it for php right syntax.

```
function addToTree($tree, $array) { 
    for ($i = 0, $length = count($array); $i < $length; $i++) {
        $tree = $tree[array[$i]] = (($i == $length - 1) ? null : $tree[array[$i]] || {})
    }
}

// or, without the i == length - 1 check in each iteration:
function addToTree(tree, array) { 
    for ($i = 0, $length = count($array); $i < $length -1; $i++) {
        $tree = $tree[array[$i]] = $tree[array[$i]] || {};
    } 
    $tree[array[$i]] = null;
}
```

Comment: I don't undestand this:

    || {} (or empty keys? how?)

Comment: I don't understand this ternary operator in javascript and how to translate it to PHP

tree = tree[array[i]] = ((i == length - 1) ? null : tree[array[i]] || {})

Comment: My translated code is this, but it doesn't works.

function addToTree($tree, $array) {
 $length = count($array);
    for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
        $tree = $tree[$array[$i]] = (($i == $length - 1) ? null : $tree[$array[$i]] || array());
    }
 return $tree;
}

Comment: Someone coul explain me this line?

$tree = $tree[array[$i]] = (($i == $length - 1) ? null : $tree[array[$i]] || {})
I'm triying to translate it to PHP but i don't undestand it.

Thaks.